# iOS 10 UserNotifications not working on migrated app

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, usernotifications

I have an app built using Swift 2.3 and tested on iOS 9.3, with local notifications and it was working fine.
As I updated my app to Swift 3 and the new UserNotifications framework the app stoped displaying notifications. I tested on a new project and my code worked just fine. The SAME code.

After a lot of tests to find the problem, the one thing that seems to be causing the problem is my bundle identifier. The new project had a different one, and when I changed to the original identifier it stoped working. Changing back to any other identifier and it started working again.

I can't change the bundle identifier, because the app is already published on app store. 
Has anyone seen something like this? Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you all!

Comment: Very interesting. You seem to have the problem completely figured out; well done. Is there anything "funny" about the "bad" bundle identifier?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what I mean; you have not revealed any of the details. You have to think about it for yourself, don't you? You say "Changing back to any other identifier and it started working again". So what is _special_ about the bundle identifier that makes it _stop_ working? It must have some feature that none of the other identifiers has.

Comment: There is nothing particular about the old identifier. Even so, that the app  was accepted to the app store with that identifier.
The old identifier was like com.mycompanyname.myappname. Changing to com.mycompanyname.myappname2 made it work. The problem is, since I already have the app published I have to make it work with the old identifier.

Comment: Well, I find that hard to believe. Everything you have said, if true, proves that there is _something_ about this one bundle id that is a problem. You need to figure out what that is. Let me ask you this: how did you test? Did you test on a device? Did this device _already_ have this app on it? If so, could _that_ be the source of the problem?

Comment: I tested the app in both my device (iPad) and an emulator. The device had the previous version of the app (not downloaded from app store), but I deleted it before testing the new version. The same happens on an emulator that didn't have the app before.

Comment: I have a similar problem, that is after migration notifications are not working (iOS 10, UserNofitications framework). In a new app, the notifications work fine. I've tried changing the bundle identifier, it did not make any change.