# iOS 10 Local Notifications not working (migrating to UserNotifications framework)

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications, unusernotificationcenter

I have an app that had local notifications working fine in iOS 9.
I am updating the app to iOS 10.
After upgrading to Swift 3, I have migrated the local notifications to new UserNotifications framework (I will only support iOS 10 so it is fine).
However, I  don't get any notifications in this app. Same code in a vanilla app works.

I've requested authorization for notifications and that part is working fine.
I've also tried adding UserNotification.framework but that does not make any difference.

What can be the reason for not seeing notifications after migrating?

Comment: Not enough info. There are a lot of steps to get notifications working. You have not proven that you've done any of them.

Comment: Interesting that you say same code in a vanilla app works, though. What happens if you change your bundle ID? Does it start working then?

Comment: No. I've changed the bundle identifier as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779370/ios-10-usernotifications-not-working-on-migrated-app, still no change.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I was thinking of.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that setting          `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in app delegate gives error message in my applications (both vanilla & migrated app) while in a downloaded demo app it is ok. I see no difference between my apps and the demo app that would cause this. The error message is _cannot assign value type AppDelegate to type UNUserNotificationCenterDelegage?_

Comment: That's very important. The delegate object must formally declare that it adopts the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol. Otherwise the delegate methods are not called.

Comment: The delegate must also be set before `application:didLaunchWithOptions:` or otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Leo Natan & Matt. I don't want to use delegate method; I just want to receive notifications. As I mentioned, there is no problem in vanilla app even though it has the same error message for setting delegate. Declaring `AppDelegate` confirming to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` solves the error message. Looks like it is a requirement in Swift 3. Thanks.

Comment: The delegate message is how you receive the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the issues is resolved. I've tried multiple things so I don't know what was the solution :(. On the other hand, I was doing one mistake which made debugging very difficult for me. Looks like the `identifier` in `UNNotificationRequest` should be unique. I used to schedule multiple notifications and set the same identifier to all of them. This caused all previous notifications to be overwritten by the very last one scheduled.

Comment: Should I or can I delete this whole question as I don't believe it will help anyone since it is not clear what the solution is?

Comment: I had a similar issue (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785105/usernotification-is-not-showing-ios-10/) and discovered that `content.body` cannot be empty for it to work. Initially I only set the title, but when I added the body, the notification would appear.  Maybe that was one of the things that you changed.